# DatePicker still allows selecting future years despite using Restrict to Current Year

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on a Flutter project where I am using a `DatePicker` to allow users to select a date. I want to restrict the selection to the current year, and I have set the `firstDate` and `lastDate` accordingly.Here's the relevant code:

```
Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
  DateTime selectedDate = DateTime.now();

  final DateTime firstAllowedDate = DateTime(DateTime.now().year);

  final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
    context: context,
    initialDate: selectedDate,
    firstDate: firstAllowedDate,
    lastDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year, 12, 31), // Restrict to current year
  );

  if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate) {
    setState(() {
      selectedDate = picked;
    });
  }
}
```

Despite setting the `firstDate` and `lastDate` to limit the selection to the current year, the `DatePicker` still allows selecting future years. Am I missing something in my implementation?

Any help or guidance on how to properly restrict the date selection to the current year would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I've tried the below code for restriction:

```
lastDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year, 12, 31), // Restrict to current year
```

PLease check attached screenshot:
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uBNF.png)

Comment: Didn't understand your Question. What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: My goal is to restrict the date selection in the Flutter DatePicker to the current year only.

Comment: Then your lastDate Code is right. You can restrict users to the current year only.

Comment: Are you perhaps confusing what values will be _shown_, which which ones can actually be _selected_ ...?

Comment: in this, I want to hide future years. @CBroe

Comment: I don't think the component you have chosen there allows for that. firstDate and lastDate specify which dates can be _selected_ by the user; and I can't spot any explicit option to determine which dates/months/years get _shown_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want like this.

Just add the below code in your code.

```
selectableDayPredicate: (DateTime date) {
        return date.isBefore(DateTime.now()) &&
            date.year <=
                DateTime.now().year; // Only allow dates in the past and years up to the current year
      },
```

[image]